# How can I specify a type when I assign a generic function to a variable

Tags: generics, types, rust

I'd like to do something conceptually like this:
`let fun: fn(&mut _) -> Result<u32> = ReadBytesExt::read_u32::<BigEndian>;`

But that doesn't work as rust thinks I'm trying to call `ReadBytesExt::read_u32` with `BigEndian` as a type arg and no other arg. (I get a wrong number of args error).

So what do I do, seems like something that rust's type system should allow, since I'm trying to be MORE specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values cannot and never will be able to contain bound generics; the concept simply cannot be accomplished due to how monomorphisation works.

Such a thing needs to be done with a wrapping function like this:

```rust
fn read_u32_be<R: Read>(&mut r: R) -> byteorder::Result<u32> {
    r.read_u32::<BigEndian>()
}
```

Comment: do you mean bound generics? because unbound generics is what I'm trying to avoid. And can you elaborate on how monomorphisation works? I've been googling around a bit but only found suggestions for implementations not what was actually used.